# Getting the value of select option not working

Tags: php, sql

I have a dropdownlist with 2 option (LOCAL and IMPORT). If I select LOCAL, I should get the value LOC while IMPORT, I should get IM. But either the two I selected, I get the value IM. Please help, how to get the value of the corresponding select option.Thanks.

```
<?php  $shipmenttype = array("0"=>"Please select", "LOC"=>"LOCAL", "IM"=>"IMPORT");?>
<td><b><select name='shiptype' id='shiptype' onchange=''>
    <?php foreach($shipmenttype as $keyname=>$ship_type):?>

        <?php 
            $selected = "";
                    $shiptype = $_POST['shiptype'];
                    if($keyname == $shiptype): $selected =" selected"; endif;       
        ?>                    
                <option value="<?php echo $keyname;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $ship_type;?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>

</select></b></td></tr>


<?php

$site = dbGetConfig("sitecode");
$dbnextID = dbNextID($keyname);

if($site=="CKI") {
$site="CK".date("Y");
}
if($site=="PQI") {
$site="PQ".date("Y");
}

$refnumb = $keyname.$site."-".str_pad($dbnextID,7,0, STR_PAD_LEFT); 

?>
```

Running Number (000000):

```
function dbNextID($key) {
$sql1 = "insert into key_master (keyname) values (:keyname)";
$sql2= "update key_master set id = id + 1 where keyname = :keyname";
$sql3 = "select id from key_master where keyname = :keyname";

$conn = dbConnect(); 
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare($sql3);

$conn->beginTransaction();
$stmt1->execute(array(':keyname' => $key));
$stmt2->execute(array(':keyname' => $key));
$stmt3->execute(array(':keyname' => $key)); 
$value = $stmt3->fetchColumn(0);
$conn->commit();
$conn=null;

return $value;
}
```

HTML Table:

```
<!--- Local Shipment --->

<table id="t1" class=normal2 style='font-size:0.6em;'>
<tr><th align='right'>Shipment Type:</th>
<td><b><input type='text' name='ship1' id='ship1' value="" readonly /></b></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>Reference Number: </th>
<td><input type='text' name='ref_no1' id='ref_no1' value="<?php echo $refnumb ?>" readonly /></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>Supplier: </th>
<td><select name='supplier1'>
    <?php foreach($data1 as $row1): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row1['SupplierName'] ?>"><?php echo $row1['SupplierName'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>Description: </th>
<td><input type='text' name='description1' size='70' /></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>PO No: </th>
<td><input type='date' name='po_no1' /></td></tr> 

<tr><th align='right'>Invoice Number: </th>
<td><input type='text' name='inv_number1' /></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>Receive Qty: </th>
<td><input type='text' name='r_qty1' /></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>No. of Boxes/Packs: </th>
<td><input type='text' name='no_boxes1' /></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'></th>
<td></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'> </th>
<td align='left'><input type='submit' name='local_add' value='SAVE' style='font-size:2em;' /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type='submit' name='local_cancel' value='CANCEL' style='font-size:2em;' /></td></tr>
</table>


<!--- Import Shipment --->

<table id="t2" class=normal2 style='font-size:0.6em;'>
<tr><th align='right'>Shipment Type:</th>
<td><b><input type='text' name='ship2' id='ship2' value="" readonly /></b></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>Reference Number: </th>
<td><b><input type='text' name='ref_no2' id='ref_no2' value="<?php echo $refnumb ?>" readonly /></b></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>Supplier: </th>
<td><select name='supplier2'>
    <?php foreach($data2 as $row2): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row2['SupplierName'] ?>"><?php echo $row2['SupplierName'] ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>Description: </th>
<td><input type='text' name='description2' size='70' /></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>PO No: </th>
<td><input type='date' name='po_no2' /></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>Invoice Number: </th>
<td><input type='text' name='inv_number2' /></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'>AWB(Airway Bill) No: </th>
<td><input type='text' name='awb_no2' /></td></tr>

    <tr><th align='right'>AWB No of Boxes/Packs: </th>
<td><input type='text' name='awb_no_boxes2' /></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'> </th>
<td></td></tr>

<tr><th align='right'> </th>
<td align='left'><input type='submit' name='import_add' value='SAVE' style='font-size:2em;' /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type='submit' name='import_cancel' value='CANCEL' style='font-size:2em;' /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
$('#shiptype').change(function () {
$('#t1,#t2').hide();
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
var strloc = "LOCAL";
var strimp = "IMPORT";

    if (selectedValue == "LOC") {
        $('#t1').show();
    $('#ship1').val(strloc);
    //$('#strkey').val(selectedValue);

    } else if (selectedValue == "IM") {
        $('#t2').show();
    $('#ship2').val(strimp);
    //$('#strkey').val(selectedValue);
    }           
 });

$('#t1,#t2').hide();

</script>
```

Comment: How do you select the two option in one dropdown  ? pls explain briefly.

Comment: The code in your question looks okay. Please add the code where you are evaluating the selected option of your dropdown.

Comment: r u looking for multiple options??

Comment: @mapek please see my updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your code:

```
$shiptype = $_POST['shiptype'];
$selected = ($shiptype == $keyname ? 'selected=""' : '');
```

**Your Full Code (Modified):**

```
<select name='shiptype' id='shiptype' onchange='' >
<?php foreach($shipmenttype as $keyname=>$ship_type):?>

<?php 
$shiptype = $_POST['shiptype'];
$selected = ($shiptype == $keyname ? 'selected=""' : '');
?>                    
<option value="<?php echo $keyname;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>>

<?php echo $ship_type;?>
</option>
<?php endforeach;?>

</select>
```

**Solution with your existing Code:**

```
$selected = "";
if($keyname == $shiptype): $selected ='selected=""'; 
endif;
```

**What i have changed?**

**just replace:**

```
$selected ="selected";
```

**With:**

```
$selected ='selected=""';
```

Comment: still getting IM for LOCAL

Comment: use **var_dump($_POST);** before if else conditions. @KimlynTormes

Comment: where exactly? I tried to put it before $shiptype = $_POST['shiptype'];
$selected = ($shiptype == $keyname ? 'selected=""' : ''); but nothing happen

Comment: No. I'm using jquery to show only the tables. I don't have submit button

Comment: <select name='shiptype' id='shiptype' onchange=''> than where is onclick function??? its empty in your code @KimlynTormes

Comment: I don't have onclick function. How should I do that anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100351/discussion-between-devpro-and-kimlyn-tormes).